# Can't move woocommerce category description to bottom of page

Tags: php, wordpress

today I think I have alot of problems. I'm only in HTML and CSS for now, i used this formula

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 ); add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );`

To move category description to bottom of my site, but it doesnt work. I added it directly in functions.php of my child theme.[This is how my code looks in functions.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONQFb.png)

I will be really thankfull, if someone give me some advice here, bcs i searched the Internet and everywhere is that formula.

What is interesting when im in admin, description dissapears, but in incognito there is in upper part of page :D

This is the site im struggling with https://rocket-mama.com/kategoria-produktu/sukienki-do-karmienia/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

May be hook will not work for it, so you can check the product archive page in your woocommerce plugin files and move it in child theme. File path should  be

you have to change the archive-product.php in

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates